Solutions of equation change in a continuously differentiable way
Let $p: B^n \rightarrow B^n$ be a polynomial that has no fixed point. Then for each $x \in B^n$ there exists a unique constant $c_x \geq 0$ such that $||(1-c_x)p(x) + c_x \cdot x|| = 1$.
How do I show that $f: B^n \rightarrow [0, \infty): x \mapsto c_x$ is continuously differentiable?
I realize that this is equivalent to $g: B^n \rightarrow [0, 2]$ being continuously differentiable where $g$ maps any $x$ to the length of the straight line that starts at $p(x)$, goes through $x$ and ends at its intersection $I(x)$ with $\partial B^n$.
The problem is also equivalent to $h: B^n \rightarrow \partial B^n : x \mapsto I(x)$ being continuously differentiable but I'm not sure which (if any) of these three formulations yields a good angle of attack.
That $g, h \in C^1$ seems intuitively true and I even suspect $g, h \in C^{\infty}$, however, I have a hard time formulating the problem more concretely and I don't see a way to use an "implicit theorem" either so that's where I'm stuck.
